# Modify package names for java classes generated from wsdl

Tags: java, wsdl

How do I modify package names for java classes generated from multiple wsdls. I have two wsdls, and both are generating classes like ObjectFactory, package-info etc with the exact same package name. As a result, I am not able to organize the imports in my code. My packages look like this for the wsdls -

```
WSDL A
    com.test.customerinfo.dto
    com.test.customerinfo.exceptions
    com.test.customerinfo.service

WSDL B    
    com.test.customerinfo.dto
    com.test.customerinfo.exceptions
    com.test.customerinfo.service
```

I want it to look something like this -

```
WSDL A
    com.test.customerinfo.dto
    com.test.customerinfo.exceptions
    com.test.customerinfo.service

WSDL B    
    com.testOne.customerinfo.dto
    com.testOne.customerinfo.exceptions
    com.testOne.customerinfo.service
```

I tried this, but it didn't work -

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
          <id>generate-sources</id>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <configuration>
             <sourceRoot>target/generated-sources/test/java</sourceRoot>
             <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                   <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/test/GetInfo.wsdl</wsdl>
                   <extraargs>
                      <extraarg>-server</extraarg>
                      <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                      <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                      <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                      <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                      <extraarg>http://dto.customerinfo.test.com/=com.test.customerinfo.dto</extraarg>
                      <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                      <extraarg>http://services.customerinfo.test.com/=com.test.customerinfo.services</extraarg>
                      <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                      <extraarg>http://exceptions.customerinfo.test.com/=com.test.customerinfo.exceptions</extraarg>
                   </extraargs>
                   <frontEnd>jaxws21</frontEnd>
                   <faultSerialVersionUID>1</faultSerialVersionUID>
                </wsdlOption>
             </wsdlOptions>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
             <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
          </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Please advise.

Comment: How do you generate the classes from wsdl? Which tool are you using? For example, if you use [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) it can be done with `-p [ wsdl-namespace= ] PackageName`

Comment: I want it to be defined in pom.xml. The option you have given here is command line.

Comment: Are you using `cxf-codegen-plugin`?

Comment: Yes I am using cxf-codegen-plugin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In `cxf-codgen-plugin` you can specify package mapping in the `wsdlOptions` section:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            ...
            <configuration>
                ...
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        ...
                        <packagenames>
                        <!-- Package Mappings -->
                            <packagename>http://namespace.example.com/=com.test.package</packagename>
                        </packagenames>
                        ...
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Or alternatively you can also use `extraarg`:

```xml
<wsdlOptions>
    <wsdlOption>
        ...
        <extraargs>
            <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
            <extraarg>http://namespace.example.com/=com.test.package</extraarg>
        </extraargs>
    </wsdlOption>
</wsdlOptions>
```

Comment: I looked at the namespaces in the wsdl, and tried this, but it didn't work -  <packagenames>
                        <!-- Package Mappings -->
                            <packagename>http://services.abc.def.com/=com.test.services</packagename>
                            <packagename>http://dto.abc.def.com/=com.test.dto</packagename>
                            <packagename>http://exceptions.abc.def.com/=com.test.exceptions</packagename>
</packagenames>

Comment: Can you post the wsdl and cxf version? I use 2.7.5

Comment: Edit your question and post the wsdl and the plugin configuration so I can try to reproduce it. I use this configuration in in several projects.

Comment: I can't post the wsdl. Sorry. Do you want me to paste the contents of my pom.xml?

Comment: Yes, please. And if you can post an "alternative" wdsl to reproduce the problem. I'll try to publish a sample project, I'm back in a while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67968/discussion-between-tobias-and-rickygrimes).

Comment: Hi, your answer actually worked. The thing that was causing trouble was the /after the end of the namespace. Instead of /=<packagename>, I had to do =<packagename>. Thank you so much.

Comment: thanks for showing the light to <packagenames> element.

Comment: It seems this option has removed in version 3.4.3