# Unable to generate java files from UPS Void wsdl: void is a Java keyword

Tags: java, maven, soap, wsdl, ups

I'm working on generating Java code from the UPS Void wsdl. However, this wsdl generates java classess with the package of:

package com.ups.wsdl.xoltws.void.v1_1;

Which doesn't compile. Void is a reserved keyword in Java.

I'm using the Maven cxf codegen plugin.

This seems like a problem that anyone generating Java code from this wsdl would run into. Has anyone done this before and found a workaround for this problem?

Here's the wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- UPS Void Shipment Service WSDL Release Date Mar 11, 2008 -->
<!-- Copyright 2007-2008 United Parcel Service of America, Inc. All rights reserved.   -->
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:error="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Error/v1.1" xmlns:upss="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0" xmlns:common="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0" xmlns:voida="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Void/v1.1" xmlns:tns="http://www.ups.com/WSDL/XOLTWS/Void/v1.1" targetNamespace="http://www.ups.com/WSDL/XOLTWS/Void/v1.1">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <!-- This schema defines the UPS Security header used for authorization purposes -->
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0" schemaLocation="UPSSecurity.xsd"/>
            <!--  This schema defines the error detail data types returned within SOAPFaults to provide more specific information pertaining to the problem. -->
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Error/v1.1" schemaLocation="Error1.1.xsd"/>
            <!-- This schema defines the Void Shipment service data types -->
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Void/v1.1" schemaLocation="VoidWebServiceSchema.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="VoidRequestMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="Body" element="voida:VoidShipmentRequest"/>
        <wsdl:part name="UPSSecurity" element="upss:UPSSecurity"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="VoidResponseMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="Body" element="voida:VoidShipmentResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="VoidErrorMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="VoidError" element="error:Errors"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="VoidPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="ProcessVoid">
            <wsdl:input name="VoidShipmentRequest" message="tns:VoidRequestMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output name="VoidShipmentResponse" message="tns:VoidResponseMessage"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="VoidError" message="tns:VoidErrorMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="VoidBinding" type="tns:VoidPortType">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="ProcessVoid">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://onlinetools.ups.com/webservices/VoidBinding/v1.1" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="VoidShipmentRequest">
                <soap:body parts="Body" use="literal"/>
                <soap:header message="tns:VoidRequestMessage" part="UPSSecurity" use="literal">
                    <soap:headerfault message="tns:VoidErrorMessage" part="VoidError" use="literal"/>
                </soap:header>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="VoidShipmentResponse">
                <soap:body parts="Body" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="VoidError">
                <soap:fault name="VoidError" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="VoidService">
        <wsdl:port name="VoidPort" binding="tns:VoidBinding">
            <!-- Production URL -->
            <!-- <soap:address location="https://onlinetools.ups.com/webservices/Void"/> -->
            <!-- CIE (Customer Integration Environment) URL -->
            <soap:address location="https://wwwcie.ups.com/webservices/Void"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: You can specify the package name of the generated code using the `-p` option. More info in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810422/specifying-package-name-when-using-maven-to-generate-java-from-wsdl).

Comment: Thanks for the QUICK response. That worked great, though I had to throw in a -autoNameResolution. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this through some flags in my Maven config:

```
<wsdlOption>
    <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/ups/ship/Void.wsdl</wsdl>
    <extraargs>
        <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
        <extraarg>-compile</extraarg>
        <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
        <extraarg>com.ups.wsdl.xoltws.voidservice</extraarg>
        <extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
    </extraargs>
</wsdlOption>
```

More details on this in: [Specifying Package Name When Using Maven to Generate Java from WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810422/specifying-package-name-when-using-maven-to-generate-java-from-wsdl)